# Installing Ubuntu on Lenovo 100S 14

Tags: lenovo, bios

Lenovo 100S-14IBR 14" Intel Celeron 2GB RAM 32GB eMMC Red Laptop

Intel® Celeron N3050 Dual-Core processor
32GB EMMC hard drive

Hi,

I want to install Linux, any full versions on that laptop above. I bought it will be delivered tomorrow.
I've read some places people saying they cannot install it on that, however I think their processors were Intel Atom. I want to get rid of Windows completely and have it as Ubuntu alone, to learn programming.

Would it work and how would I get pass BIOS to install it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and Ubuntu and xUbuntu works fine without any problems.
To select boot option you need to switch off your laptop and press and hold bios button (small button next of PowerButton) and you will see the bios menu.

Comment: and during installation do not forget to create uefi partition for your Ubuntu OS :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to craft a bootable USB from the downloaded Ubuntu 16.04LTS ISO.  Then, as stated above, press the small detented button to the right of the power button (use a key or ball point pen) and select boot order.  Then boot to that USB and install.  I selected the simple 'erase disk and install' option on the eMMC and most everything worked - I still can't get the MicroSD reader to work - not sure why.

I switched my IBR from Windows because 32G wasn't enough space to do the latest Windows updates - so I tossed Windows out the door.

Certainly loving the battery life on mine.  Not so sure about the unicorn stickers my daughter left on it...